# Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined, Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, promise, setstate, async.js

I have a simple code, but I receiving (sometimes) wrong results, it's because of NodeJS async, I know. Finally I need do update "this.setState({active: options})". So to solve the issue of async of NodeJS I used the require("async") library. But now my simple code got quite complex, and the result is also not 100% good.

And also at the on "function road" when i use the "this.setState({actove: options})", or "this.setState({actove: results.optionsFill})", I receive errors: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" and "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined".

Please see the simple start code (the code calculates the legend input to a map, the arr for number periods):

```
    setLegend(data){

        function roundingSize(number){
        }

        function rounding(number){
        }

        function stopsArrFill(jumpLegendValue, highestNumber){
        }

        // Searching for the highestNumber POPULATION
        var highestNumber = 0

        data.features.forEach(element => {
             var value = element.properties["POPULATION"]           
             if(highestNumber<value) highestNumber = value
        })

        // Need to round the number, so it will look nice on the legend
        highestNumber = roundingSize(highestNumber)

        // Searching for the LowestNumber POPULATION
        var LowestNumber = highestNumber

        data.features.forEach(element => {
            var value = element.properties["POPULATION"]
            if(LowestNumber>value) LowestNumber = value
        })

        // Need to round the number, so it will look nice on the legend
        LowestNumber = roundingSize(LowestNumber)

        // 7 because 1 element is 0 and the last is the highestNumber, so it gives 7 empty elements to fill
        var jumpLegendValue = Math.round(rounding((highestNumber - LowestNumber)/7))

        var tmpStops  = stopsArrFill(jumpLegendValue, highestNumber)

        const options = {
            name: 'Legenda',
            description: 'Liczba wystąpień',
            property: 'POPULATION',
            stops: tmpStops
        }

        this.setState({active: options})
```

Now the complex code with async.auto:

```
    setLegend(data){

        function roundingSize(number){
        }

        function rounding(number){
        }

        function stopsArrFill(jumpLegendValue, highestNumber){
        }

        async.auto({

            highestNumber: function(callback){

                // Searching for the highestNumber POPULATION
                var highestNumber = 0

                data.features.forEach(element => {
                    var value = element.properties["POPULATION"]           
                    if(highestNumber<value) highestNumber = value
                })

                // Need to round the number, so it will look nice on the legend
                highestNumber = roundingSize(highestNumber)

                callback(null, highestNumber)
            },
            lowestNumber: ['highestNumber', function(results, callback){

                // Searching for the LowestNumber POPULATION
                var lowestNumber = results.highestNumber

                data.features.forEach(element => {
                    var value = element.properties["POPULATION"]
                    if(lowestNumber>value) lowestNumber = value
                })

                // Need to round the number, so it will look nice on the legend
                lowestNumber = roundingSize(lowestNumber)

                callback(null, lowestNumber)
            }],
            jumpLegendValue: ['highestNumber', 'lowestNumber', function(results, callback){

                // 7 because 1 element is 0 and the last is the highestNumber, so it gives 7 empty elements to fill
                var jumpLegendValue = Math.round(rounding((results.highestNumber - results.lowestNumber)/7))

                callback(null, jumpLegendValue)
            }],
            stopsArrFill:['highestNumber','jumpLegendValue', function(results, callback){

                // Filling the stops with jumpLegendValues
                var tmpStops  = stopsArrFill(results.jumpLegendValue, results.highestNumber)

                callback(null, tmpStops)
            }],
            optionsFill:['stopsArrFill', function(results, callback){

                const options = {
                    name: 'Legenda',
                    description: 'Liczba wystąpień',
                    property: 'POPULATION',
                    stops: results.stopsArrFill
                }      

                callback(null, options)
            }],
            function (err, results)
            {
                this.setState({active:results.optionsFill})
                console.log('error: ', err)
            }
        })
```

I am now playing around with this for 2 days, do you  have any ideas / suggestions? I couldn't find any similar usage for setState with async.auto.

Comment: Use arrow functions instead of `function` to preserve the context of `this`.

Comment: Is it intentional that `.highestNumber` is a function but `.lowestNumber`, `.jumpLegendValue`, `.stopsArrFill` and `.optionsFill` are arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the setState issue, you need to be aware that the async.auto({}) is a promise.

The final error function need to be deleted this code:

```
function (err, results)
{
    this.setState({active:results.optionsFill})
    console.log('error: ', err)
}
```

and at the end of async.auto({}) need to add:

```
.then((result)=>{
    this.setState({active: result.optionsFill})
})
```